# SQL Server 2008 merging the result of two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to merge the result of both the queries below using the UNION operator in SQL Server 2008 but got the following error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.

My code:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    CITY, LEN(CITY) 
FROM 
    table1 
ORDER BY 
    LEN (CITY), CITY ASC

UNION

SELECT TOP 1 
    CITY, LEN(CITY) 
FROM 
    table1 
ORDER BY 
    LEN (CITY) DESC, CITY ASC
```

Any comments would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: order by should be used in second query only

Comment: why do you need to select same record twice from same table?

Comment: but still this doesn't solve the problem. It doesn't merge the result of the two queries

Comment: Kashif, the two queries have different criteria as a result producing different records

Comment: For your second point; use `union all` instead of `union`; otherwise duplicates are removed; and given you're selecting the same stuff from the same table, everything will be a duplicate.

Comment: are you getting same error by removing order by clause from first select statement

Comment: Lets say table1 contains city names Arizona, Atlanta, Omaha, Arkansas. So the first query should give output Atlanta | 7 and the second query should give Arkansas | 8. the corresponding numbers are as the result of LEN (CITY). I am trying to merge the result of these two queries.

Comment: @JohnLBevan close.  len(city) desc on one vs asc on the other. and algo OMAHA would be first at 5 and arkansas at 8 last.

Comment: yeah my mistake OMAHA should be there instead of Atlanta..but you have got what am trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct way to do it

```
Select * From 
(
SELECT TOP 1 
    CITY, cityLen = LEN(CITY) 
FROM 
    table1 
ORDER BY 
    cityLen, CITY ASC
) a
UNION
Select * From 
(
SELECT TOP 1 
    CITY, cityLen = LEN(CITY) 
FROM 
    table1 
ORDER BY 
    cityLen DESC, CITY ASC
) b
```

or using `Row_Number` window function

```
select * from
(
select *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LEN (CITY) DESC, CITY ASC) as Drn,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LEN (CITY) ASC, CITY ASC) as Arn,
FROM table1 
) a
where 1 in (Arn,Drn)
```

Comment: the first code gave me the following errors No column name was specified for column 2 of 'a'.No column name was specified for column 2 of 'b'.

Comment: just alias len(city) as lenCity on the 1st query inner select `SELECT TOP 1 
    CITY, LEN(CITY)  as lenCity`  though I like `union all` here instead of union

Comment: @xQbert thought about it since it is just two records didnt mention it

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ASC order command in your first select statement. You can only order the result at the end of any query as ordering in the middle of a query (if allowed) would cause many problems in getting consistent results.

EDIT: I realized the table were the same, you need to use Union ALL, or as stated in other comments, the duplicates are taken out in a UNION.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    CITY, LEN(CITY) 
FROM 
    table1 

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP 1 
    CITY, LEN(CITY) 
FROM 
    table1 
ORDER BY 
    LEN (CITY) DESC, CITY ASC
```

Comment: Yet this doesn't solve the problem...it hasn't merged the results

Comment: What are you trying to merge? You are using the union against the same table?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use Common table expression. Try this

```
;With cte
AS (
select * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  LEN (CITY) DESC, CITY ASC) as rn
    FROM table1 
    )
    select * from cte where rn = 1
    union 
    select * from cte where rn = 1
```